# Batch - If, ElseIf, Else

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Whats wrong with this code?

```
IF "%language%" == "de" (
    goto languageDE
) ELSE (
    IF "%language%" == "en" (
    goto languageEN
) ELSE (
    echo Not found.
)
```

I'm not really good in Batch..

Comment: Compare your parens to your indents.  Should be illuminating.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
@echo off
title Test

echo Select a language. (de/en)
set /p language=

IF /i "%language%"=="de" goto languageDE
IF /i "%language%"=="en" goto languageEN

echo Not found.
goto commonexit

:languageDE
echo German
goto commonexit

:languageEN
echo English
goto commonexit

:commonexit
pause
```

The point is that batch simply continues through instructions, line by line until it reaches a `goto`, `exit` or end-of-file. It has no concept of `sections` to control flow.

Hence, entering `de` would jump to `:languagede` then simply continue executing instructions until the file ends, showing `de` then `en` then `not found`.

Comment: Can you add these shortcuts inside a for loop?

Comment: The /I switch to IF does case-insensitive string comparisons.
You can type HELP IF for more information about IF.

Answer (score 28):

```
@echo off

set "language=de"

IF "%language%" == "de" (
    goto languageDE
) ELSE (
    IF "%language%" == "en" (
        goto languageEN
    ) ELSE (
        echo Not found.
    )
)

:languageEN
:languageDE

echo %language%
```

This works , but not sure how your language variable is defined.Does it have spaces in its definition.

Comment: Don't forget that after `echo Not found.` it will drop through. So call `exit` or `goto` somewhere else.

Answer (score 12):

batchfiles perform simple string substitution with variables.
so, a simple

```
goto :language%language%
echo notfound
...
```

does this without any need for if.

Comment: Ok additional thing: What if there could be the case that the label is not defined? Any way to get around WITH this code?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation.  Do not use user-added REM statements to block batch steps.  Use conditional GOTO instead.
That way you can predefine and test the steps and options.  The users also get much simpler changes and better confidence.

```
@Echo on
rem Using flags to control command execution

SET ExecuteSection1=0
SET ExecuteSection2=1

@echo off

IF %ExecuteSection1%==0 GOTO EndSection1
ECHO Section 1 Here

:EndSection1

IF %ExecuteSection2%==0 GOTO EndSection2
ECHO Section 2 Here
:EndSection2
```

Answer (score 1):

As @cHao commented, the **opening parentheses** number is **higher** (*+1*) than the **closing ones**'. The 2 **need to be equal** (to be more precise, the "***(***" just after the 1<sup>st</sup> *ELSE* should not be there).

Check [[MS.Learn]: if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if) (or `help if`, personally I prefer [[SS64]: IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)) for more details.

Because of the fact that each branch only contains a [[SS64]: GOTO](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html), the whole block could be rewritten as 2 independent *If* commands (simpler), but this is a generic form and other commands could be added in each branch (yes, *Batch* **does** allow (some degree of) structuring).

*script00.bat*:

```bat
@echo off


if "%LANGUAGE%" == "de" (
    goto :languageDE
) else if "%LANGUAGE%" == "en" (
    goto :languageEN
) else (
    echo Not found.
)


goto :eof


:languageDE
    echo Deutsche.
    goto :eof


:languageEn
    echo English.
    goto :eof
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q025384358]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> script00.bat
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> for %g in (dummy de ro en x) do (set LANGUAGE=%g& script00.bat)
>
> [prompt]> (set LANGUAGE=dummy  & script00.bat)
> Not found.
>
> [prompt]> (set LANGUAGE=de  & script00.bat)
> Deutsche.
>
> [prompt]> (set LANGUAGE=ro  & script00.bat)
> Not found.
>
> [prompt]> (set LANGUAGE=en  & script00.bat)
> English.
>
> [prompt]> (set LANGUAGE=x  & script00.bat)
> Not found.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
color 0a
set /p language=
if %language% == DE (
    goto LGDE
) else (
    if %language% == EN (
    goto LGEN
    ) else (
    echo N/A
)

:LGDE
(code)
:LGEN
(code)
```